# How to set task ID of first task in a celery chain?

Tags: python, celery

I have something like this

```
from uuid import uuid4
task_id = uuid4()
(task1.s(args..) | task2.s() | task3.s()).apply_async(task_id=task_id)
```

Now I want this custom task_id to be the task ID for the first task `task1` but it is different when I tried to log it from `task1` using `self.request.id`

How can I set a custom ID here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to pass task_id to first task in your chain you should call [`.subtask()`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=subtask#celery.app.task.Task.subtask) which expose more options than `.s()` or `.si()`:

```
from celery.utils import uuid
first_task_id = uuid()

(task1.subtask(args=(..), task_id=first_task_id) | task2.s() | task3.s()).apply_async()
```

Answer (score 3):

Just:

```
from uuid import uuid4
task_id = uuid4()
(task1.s(args..).set(task_id=task_id) | task2.s() | task3.s()).apply_async()
```